# Dynamic import and component rendering by string name

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a data set for some simple actions.  Each action has a corresponding color and [Material-UI icon](https://material-ui.com/components/material-icons/). There are about 1,100 available icons.  The data looks like this:

```
{ "items":
[{ "action": "Run",
        "icon": "DirectionsRunIcon",
        "color":"Red"},
{ "action": "Jump",
        "icon": "ArrowUpwardIcon",
        "color":"Blue"},
{ "action": "Walk",
        "icon": "DirectionsWalkIcon",
        "color":"Green"},
]}
```

Each of the icons requires importing a separate library like so:

```
import ArrowUpwardIcon from '@material-ui/icons/ArrowUpward'
```

I could be using any number of icons from `@material-ui/icons/` and they're obviously stored as a string in the data.  So the question is, how can I conditionally render the icons and only load what I need?

Currently I have a function that just does a huge switch, which won't work long term.

```
function getIcon(action) {
  switch (action) {
    case "Run":
      return <DirectionsRunIcon />;
    case "Jump":
      return <ArrowUpwardIcon />;
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using something like `@loadable/component`, you could try to load dynamicly the icon with

```
import loadable from '@loadable/component';

const Icon = ({name, ...rest}) => {
  const ImportedIcon = loadable(() =>
    import(`@material-ui/icons/${name}`),
  );

  return <ImportedIcon {...rest} />;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already have the reference name of the Icon in your datset, you may use the function below:

```
import { find } from 'lodash';

const getIcon = (action) => {
  const requiredObj = find(items, { action }) || {};
  return requiredObj.icon;
};
```

Now, you can use the resulting name to do a dynamic import.